# in/at the intersection of/between

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I wonder which form(s) are correct amongst the following:

1. we work on a research problem **at** the intersection **between** biology and computer science.
2. we work on a research problem **at** the intersection **of** biology and computer science.
3. we work on a research problem **in** the intersection **between** biology and computer science.
4. we work on a research problem **in** the intersection **of** biology and computer science.

Comment: Could one of the close  voter explains why they think this question is "too broad"?

Answer (score 4):

Number 2 is correct:

> 2. we work on a research problem **at** the intersection **of** biology and computer science.

According to [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intersection), "intersection" is appropriate if we consider the following definitions:

> **intersection**
>
> - a place or area where two or more things (such as streets) intersect;
> - the set of elements common to two or more sets; *especially*: the set of points common to two geometric configurations;

In the context of the question, the problem is about biology as well as about computer science.

Comment: can *intersection* be used this way?

Comment: I added info in the answer.

Comment: It'd to be great if the downvoter could explain their vote.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are also not so nice netizens around, and they down-vote as a sport. I suspect (without proof) that some of them feel threatened and "fight" against others for reputation. **Ignore them, the way I do.**

Answer (score 4):

Given its set theory use, you can be ***in*** an intersection as well as ***at*** it. Either works, though whether it will seem odd to someone depends on their background. Similarly, intersections can be ***of*** or ***between*** two things, and I suspect that which is preferred depends on dialect and possibly context (such as academic subject).

This is gut feel more than anything else, but I would go for ***at*** and ***of***, if your intention is to produce minimal surprise in a general audience.